# Converting date format format from dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy/mm/dd using C

Tags: c, date, segmentation-fault

The inner while loop executes infinitely though the value of `i = n` which is finite.
It compiles but shows segmentation fault.

**My Code**

```
char s[]="22/02/1997",r[20],temp[20];
int i,j,k,z,n;
for(n=strlen(s)-1; n>=0; n=i)
{
    i=n;
    k=0;
    while(s[i]!='/' || s[i]!='-')
    {
        temp[k++]=s[i];
        i--;
    }
    i--;
    for(z=strlen(temp)-1,j=0; z>=0; z--,j++)
    {
        r[j]=temp[z];
    }
    temp[0]='\0';  //empty the array
}
printf("%s",r);
```

Comment: Following [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) this `s[i]!='/' || s[i]!='-'` is the same as `!(s[i] == '/' && s[i] == '-')` which would evaluate to false (and with this end the  `while`-loop) *only* if `s[i]` equals `'/'` and `'-'` at the same time, which will *never* be the case.

Comment: In the `while` loop when reaching the nb of day there is no control to stop it as there is no slash after. better adding `i>=0`

Comment: `j=0` should be outside the first `for` loop.

Comment: As you are going to reuse the `temp` array you cannot empty it by changing only the **first character** to null character.

Comment: did the below answer solved your query?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues in your code.

1. The `j = 0` will be outside of all loop. Which means it have to be placed in starting of outer for loop.
2. You did not handled the assign null value correctly. In any place you did not assigned the null at end of the array.
3. Your expected answer is `yyyy/mm/dd`. But you did not assigned the `/` or `-` to the output.
4. In while loop, you have add one more condition also, that is checking the value of the i is greater than or equal to 0. If this condition is not there, then it tries to access the -1th position in array, it is not allocated. So, only you get the segmentation fault error.

Finally I have corrected these all mistakes. Try the below code it will works fine as you expected.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char s[]="12/02/1997",r[50],temp[50];
    int i,j,k,z,n;
    j = 0;
    for(n=strlen(s)-1; n>=0; n=i)
    {
        i=n;
        k=0;
        while(s[i]!='/' && s[i]!='-' && i >= 0)
        {
            temp[k++]=s[i];
            i--;
        }
        i--;
        temp[k] = '\0';
        for(z=strlen(temp)-1; z>=0; z--,j++)
        {
            r[j]=temp[z];
        }
        if(i >= 1) // If the i is greater than 1, then only it have a slash or hypen
        {
            r[j++] = s[i + 1]; //Assigning the / or - to the output.
        }
        temp[0]='\0';  //empty the array
    }
    r[j] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",r); 
}
```

Comment: I was checking that only. Just wait few minutes. I will update my answer.

Comment: +2 votes and the while control expression still **not correct** Try executing it with  `i=1` (Seg. Fault)

Comment: If I set the i=1, It gives the stack smashing error.

Comment: So you need to add  control on that variable: `i>=0`

Comment: Doesn't work for `"12/02/1997"`. Check your code again !

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス - you are nitpicking a lot on sureshkumar but maybe you should take a second look at your own code first.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス : I missed one condition checking and in while condition I made wrong. That is I have to check the condition with 0. Now see my answer. I was updated.

Comment: @4386427 I wasn't intended to post actually for this question but seeing no answers I tried to post a working code but OP needs to improve it.

Comment: @sureshkumar you can remove the `memset` line. Your code will still be working.

Answer (score 1):

> The inner while loop executes infinitely ....

That is because you use OR (aka `||`) instead of AND (aka `&&`). So your condition

```
(s[i] != '/' || s[i] != '-')
```

will always be true. It should at least be (see later code):

```
(s[i] != '/' && s[i] != '-')
```

> .... but shows segmentation fault.

That is a consequence of the infinite loop. Since the loop keeps incrementing/decrementing `k` and `i`, you'll end up using indexes outside the array boundary which causes the crash.

Further you should check that `i` doesn't become `-1` and, for completeness, check that `k` doesn't get too large.

You should also make sure to terminate the `temp` string as you are using `strlen(temp)`

Something like:

```
while(i>=0 && k<19 &&s[i]!='/' && s[i]!='-')
{
    temp[k++]=s[i];
    i--;
}
temp[k] = '\0';  // Terminate temp
```

Notice: There are some problems with your second loop as well but once you have solved the above, you can start looking into that part.

Comment: The control on variable `k` is useless in this case.

Comment: @Meninx-メネンックス - With a fixed input, yes, but once the code is being use with some dynamic input, it is better to be safe and protect against overflow.